# Jquery- How to display the selected dropdown value as a dropdown option

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown which I need to fill with the selected value.
Here is the code for it:

```
<select name="selectedRegion" id="selectedRegion">
<option>Washington DC</option>
<option>New york</option>
<option>Portland</option>
</select>
```

Below is the js code:

```
var regions = [];
var values = $('#selectedRegion').children('option').each(function(i, e){
     regions.push({id:e.value, name:$(e).html(),select:$(e).is(':selected')?true:false});

    });
```

Here I'm checking if the value for the dropdown is selected, if so I'm trying to display that as the selected dropdown option. How can I achieve this. I have tried getting the value of the selected option and displaying it as a text. didn't work..:( Any clue how can this be done??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
var regions = [];
$('#selectedRegion').children('option').each(function(i, e){
     regions.push({id:e.value, name:$(e).text(),select:this.selected});
}); 
var values=$('#selectedRegion').val() ? true : false;
alert(values);
```

Change you **html** like,

```
<select name="selectedRegion" id="selectedRegion">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="W">Washington DC</option>
   <option value="N">New york</option>
   <option value="P">Portland</option>
</select>
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/uCeM8/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this with text method instead of value:

```
var regions = [];
var values = $('#selectedRegion').children('option').each(function(i, e){
     regions.push({id:$(e).text(), name:$(e).text(),select:$(e).is(':selected')?true:false});

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This assignment does not make any sense.

```
var values = $('#selectedRegion').children('option').each(function(i, e){
     regions.push({id:e.value, name:$(e).html(),select:$(e).is(':selected')?true:false});

    });
```

You're assigning a loop to a variable.

you could do this,

```
$('#selectedRegion').children('option').each(function(i, e){
     var _t = $(this);

     regions.push({id: _t.value, name: _t.text(), select: _t.is(":selected")});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var regions=$('#selectedRegion>option').toArray().map(function(e){
     return {id: e.value, name: $(e).text(), select: $(e).is(":selected")};
});
```